# Return a promise from a generator function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, generator

I currently have a promisified function (that returns a promise to another function that calls it) that has some logic that goes like this:

```
function( param1,param2 ){
    if( condition1 ){
        return function1();
    }

    if( condition2 ){
        return function2().then(
            () => {
                // blah blah
                return promsie;
            }
        )
    }
}
```

`function1()` and `function2()` are both promisified functions. However, sometimes the `then` chain gets complicated. I would love to move to generators.

Is this the right way to port to generators without breaking the outer function which simply expects a promise but does nothing with it:

```
function(param1,param2){
    co(function*(){
        if( condition1 ){
             let result = yield function1();
             this.return( result );   
        }
        if( condition2 ){
            let result = yield function2();
            this.return( result )
        }
    });
    return Q();
}
```

Comment: What is `this.return()`? Where did you get `Q()` from?

Comment: @Bergi Here's the [this.return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/return) and `Q` is the npm `q` module. Excluded the requires for brevity.

Comment: But… `this` is not a generator, you cannot call `.return` from within the running generator but only from outside, and you should just use `return` statements? Also `Q()` is just an empty promise that immediately fulfills with `undefined`, not waiting for anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`co` returns a promise [co documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co)

```
co(function*(){
    var myValue;

    if( condition1 ){
         myValue = yield function1(); 
    }
    else if( condition2 ){
        myValue = yield function2();
    }

    return myValue;
})
.then(function(value){
  console.log(value); // will output myValue
})
.catch(...);
```

So if you want to modify your function you can do the following

```
function myFunc(param1,param2){
  return co(function*(){
      var myValue;

      if( condition1 ){
           myValue = yield function1(); 
      }
      else if( condition2 ){
          myValue = yield function2();
      }

      return myValue;
  });
}
```

This way you can use it somewher else

```
myFunc(param1,param2)
  .then(function(value) {
    console.log(value); // will output myValue
  });
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, after moving to `co`, my first if condition can be left as-is considering that promises are composable an `co` returns a promise. It's the second `if` that needs changing because it needs some `yield`ing.

Comment: I updated the code to `else if` is it what you want? In the previous code example even if `condition1` is true original value is overwritten if `condition2` holds

Comment: no, moving to `if-else` isnt what I was wondering about. I was wondering about how `co` and promises would work togetehr :)

Comment: I was not sure what you exactly was asking in your second question and thought it is `else-if` related. In any cases my example shows that `co` returns a promise and how you can use its result afterwards.